# input and output format for Swagger YAML

Tags: yaml, swagger, google-cloud-ml

I followed the below tutorial to create my machine learning app in Google Cloud:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ml-on-gcp/tree/master/sklearn/gae_serve#steps

I need to construct a 'modelserve.yaml' at first to define my input and output such as this file:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ml-on-gcp/blob/master/sklearn/gae_serve/default/modelserve.yaml

I know that I have multiple lines of strings for my input and multiple lines of double number (1.0 and 0.0) for the output. I described it in this question:
[Google cloud ML with Scikit-Learn raises: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lower'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689145/google-cloud-ml-with-scikit-learn-raises-dict-object-has-no-attribute-lower)

Now I could not find related documentation to tell how to struct this YAML file. What is the correct format of this file in my case?